# Search form with acts_as_taggable_on (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a searchbox to search for products.  Each product has a title and is tagged with multiple tags.

I want to be able to search for products by title or tag.  In other words if I have a product called "Green Tea" and another product tagged "green, red, blue" and I type "green" into the searchbox, I'd like both products to appear in the search results.

I am using Rails 3, acts_as_taggable_on, Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your controller, the action that displays the search results could look something like this (where :q is your query string from the search box):

```
def results
  @products = Product.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%") \
    | Product.tagged_with("%#{params[:q]}%")
end
```

Comment: I don't understand this syntax... do you need a gem or something?

Comment: The only gem this relies on is "acts as taggable" where the query above uses the "tagged_with" method.  That aside, Jamie is demonstrating how to use Postgres' built in widcard functionality!  +1 internets to you sir jamie