# How to make a search form with acts_as_taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a search form to search for images by their tags. The form kinda works, it sends the parameters to the /search_results page but it sends as this:

```
search_results?utf8=✓&search=squid%2C+color&x=0&y=0
```

And here is my form:

```
<%= form_tag ("/search_results"), :method => "get", :class=>"search_form" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag ("search"), nil, :class => 'search_input',
    :onblur=>"if(this.value=='')this.setAttribute('class', 'search_input');",
    :onfocus=>"this.setAttribute('class', 'search_input_clear');"
 %>
  <%= image_submit_tag("search.png") %>
<% end %>
```

and and my route/controller:

```
match "/search_results/" => "index#search_results", :via => :get, :as =>"search_results"
class IndexController < ApplicationController

def search_results
  @tattoos = Tattoo.tagged_with("%#{params[:search]}%")
end
```

But I never get any results.

Rails console shows this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"color, animals", "x"=>"0", "y"=>"0"}
  SQL (0.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE (name LIKE '\\%color' OR name LIKE 'animals\\%')
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tattoos` WHERE (1 = 0)
  Tattoo Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tattoos`.* FROM `tattoos` WHERE (1 = 0) ORDER BY tattoos.created_at DESC
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is yet, although it looks like you're using a parameter "q" in the action, but "search" (oddly in parentheses?) in the form.

Comment: I was trying to piece together this search function from the link I just posted and the ruby api on text_field_tag

Comment: What's the actual problem? Seems like the field tag helper is doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: Take a look at the linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090682/search-form-with-acts-as-taggable-on-rails-3

Comment: it's not passing in the search parameters, its passing stuff like: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"jesse smith, sleeve, color", "x"=>"14", "y"=>"10"}, so the controller cant find any matching records

Comment: I fixed up my question for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the % surrounding my params and that seemed to do the trick:

def search_results
  @tattoos = Tattoo.tagged_with("#{params[:search]}")
end